# detect soft navigation in getServerSideProps in Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I know that in Nextjs that after the first loading it will act as regular react app and that server data functions as getServerSideProps will act as regular end point that returns the next page data as json and navigate to next page without reloading - soft navigation -

So mt question is how can I know in getServerSideProps that the request coming from soft navigation after first Loading or not

Answer (score 0):

you can use `next/headers` to detect soft vs hard navigation (as mentioned in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/49824)). Below is the code.

> but do note that you lose static rendering of each page where you use next/headers

from Nextjs [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/headers#headers)

> headers() is a Dynamic Function whose returned values cannot be known ahead of time. Using it in a layout or page will opt a route into dynamic rendering at request time.

```js
import { headers } from 'next/headers'

isHardNavigation = () => {
  return !headers().has('next-url')
}
```

---

Although if your intention is to transition content with soft navigation. Check out view transitions API

- https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/42658
- https://developer.chrome.com/docs/web-platform/view-transitions/